# Nonreduced quadric hypersurfaces

Tags: algebraic-geometry, finite-fields, projective-schemes, birational-geometry, projective-varieties

I am reading a text in which one speaks of quadric hypersurfaces $\mathcal{Q}$ (in $\mathbb{P}^n(k)$ with $k$ a finite field) which are "everywhere nonreduced."

What does this mean ? (And is there a difference with general fields ?)

What would be the classification of everywhere nonreduced quadric hypersurfaces $\mathcal{Q}$ in $\mathbb{P}^n(k)$ ($k$ still a finite field) ?

Answer (score 1):

This might mean two different things.

First, among quadric hypersurfaces there are hypersurfaces which are everywhere non-reduced. These are double planes (their equations are squares of linear functions).

Second, one could mean a subscheme, whose associated reduced scheme is a (reduced) quadric hypersurface, but whose scheme structure is everywhere non-reduced.

Comment: @ Sasha: in the first case, what would be the precise definition of "everywhere nonreduced" ? Thanks.

Comment: The subscheme defined by an ideal $I$ is everywhere non-reduced if $\mathrm{supp}(I_{red}/I) = \mathrm{supp}(\mathcal{O}/I_{red})$, where $I_{red}$ is the corresponding radical ideal.

Comment: @ Sasha: is there a way to explain this "geometrically" in a precise sense -- so without passing to the algebra ? Or on the level of the quadratic equation of $\mathcal{Q}$ ?

Comment: If you want to make an algebraic geometry statement precise, you need some algebra.

Comment: @ Sasha: is there a connection between "reducible" and "everywhere nonreduced" ? I have never seen the term "everywhere nonreduced" in the case of quadrics over finite fields -- could you think of a reason why that is ?

Comment: In the affine case, "reducible" means the ring of functions has zero divisors; while "non-reduced" means there are nilpotents. "Everywhere non-reduced", in a sense, means that there are "many" nilpotents.